# Typescript & React. Ensure there's one child of specific type in children on compile time

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I wonder if is it possible, on Typescript side, to make sure that a react Component receives one child of a `x` type, independ on whatever else it receives.

Here's a use case:

In a "System Design" like aproach, i have a `Section` Component, and a `Title` Component as well. I want to make sure that all `Section`s receive at **least one** `Title` as child (One `h1`, or at least one `h2` more specifically), and still receives any other children (or not, whatevs).

So those would be valid:

```js
<Section ...>
    <Title level={1}>Title</Title>
    ...
</Section>

<Section ...>
    <Title level={1}>Title</Title>
    <Title level={2}>Sub-title</Title>
    ...
</Section>

<Section ...>
    <Title level={2}>Title</Title>
    <Title level={2}>Sub-title</Title>
    <Title level={2}>yada-yada</Title>
    ...
</Section>
```

Those would not:

```js
<Section ...>
    <p>some text</p>
    ...
</Section>

<Section ...>
    <Title level={1}>Title</Title>
    <Title level={1}>Other Title</Title>
    ...
</Section>

<Section ...>
    <Title level={3}>Title</Title>
    ...
</Section>
```

For now, inside component, i'm looping through children, and if no matching `Title` is found, an Error is thrown:

```js
if (!sectionTitle) throw new Error(...)
```

So, a future dev using it wrong, gets warned by the browser.

But i would really like to do this check on Typescript, so the error show up on build, and not only after opening the page.

There is a way to do that?

Here's a minimal and clear working example:
https://codesandbox.io/s/romantic-surf-tpyojt?file=/src/components/Section.tsx

Comment: Please provide a [mre] that clearly demonstrates the issue you are facing.  Ideally someone could paste the code into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground (link here!)](https://tsplay.dev/NrKM2m) and immediately get to work solving the problem without first needing to re-create it.  So there should be no pseudocode, typos, unrelated errors, or undeclared types or values.

Comment: I don't understand how the second example in invalid examples is invalid? There's at least one Title component that's level 1

Comment: @youdateme. Because that part in the parentheses: (*One* h1, or *at least one* h2 more specifically). But "at least one [any tipe of] title" should be enough really

Comment: @jcalz Here's a minimal and clear working example:
https://codesandbox.io/s/romantic-surf-tpyojt?file=/src/components/Section.tsx. Also updated the question to add it

Comment: The example should also be in plaintext in the question; please see [ask] for more information.